# easy "undo" in functional data structures

Tags: data-structures, haskell, functional-programming, immutability

I've heard that one of the benefits of purely functional data structures is that you get undo/redo operations for free. Can someone explain why? I don't see why adding undo/redo is easier in a functional language.

For example, suppose I have the following implementation of a queue:

```
data Queue a = Queue [a] [a]

newQueue :: Queue a
newQueue = Queue [] []

empty :: Queue a -> Bool
empty (Queue [] []) = True
empty _ = False

enqueue :: Queue a -> a -> Queue a
enqueue (Queue xs ys) y = Queue xs (y:ys)

dequeue :: Queue a -> (a, Queue a)
dequeue (Queue [] []) = error "Queue is empty!"
dequeue (Queue [] ys) = dequeue (Queue (reverse ys) [])
dequeue (Queue (x:xs) ys) = (x, Queue xs ys)
```

How would I modify this to get undo and redo operations? (I could imagine that the enqueue and dequeue functions also return two lists, one of the lists being all the previous versions of the queue and the other list being all the future versions of the queue, and these lists act as our undo/redo operations, but I'm guessing this isn't what people typically have in mind.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Example:

```
q1 = newQueue
q2 = enque q1 3
```

then `q1` is the undo of `q2`, since all values are immutable.  Just keep a reference to the prior value.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to point out, along with the fact that this is a feature of purity and immutability more than functional programming.

Comment: Yes, I could do the same in a number of languages, including Java.

Answer (score 11):

The reason undo/redo is easier to implement in purely functional code is because of two guarantees:

- operations are side-effect free
- data structures are immutable

You can always revert back to an old data structure as long as you maintain a reference to it.  If you want to store the entire history, you could keep it in a list:

```
trackHistory :: Queue a -> [Queue a] -> [Queue a]
trackHistory currentQueue history = currentQueue : history
```

Obviously in a real application you would want to cap the history size, but you get the idea. This works because you can guarantee that each of the queues in your list hasn't been changed.

Comment: another feature that makes undo/redo cheap is sharing. e.g. several versions of list can share common parts in memory.

Comment: @maxtaldykin Do you have any idea how one might recreate JavaScript's prototypical inheritance data structure in a purely functional way? There's a phd disseration by Alessandro Warth that implements scoped side effects using the prototypical inheritance in JS. It essentially creates an immutable tree, where every modification is a new JS object that inherits from the previous object. You can read from all history, but any modifications mask the previous key/value properties. You also end up sharing existing data, and storing only the deltas in the new object versions.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, sorry, I don'k know how to answer your questions. Thanks for pointing to Warth's dissertation, I'll try to look at it.

Comment: Ok, it's called the Worlds concept.